# Treeviewitem with images programmatically

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I have this code for creating the `TreeViewitems` which I later add to the `TreeView`. This is all done programmatically.

```
TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem {
                                        Header = ni.name,
                                        Uid = itemName,
                                        Background = color 
                                    };
```

I wanna be able to add images as icons for the `TreeViewItems` programmatically. I am doing this but all I can see in the `TreeView` is items named as `System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel` which is weird. Also there are no images shown. I am using this in my code. Please help:

```
TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem
{
    Header = new System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel
    {
        Children = 
        {
            new System.Windows.Controls.Image{Source = b},
            new System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
            {
                Text = ni.name
            }
        }
    },

    Uid = itemName,
    Background = color
};
```

I also tried the `XAML based` approach. My `XAML based` approach looks like below
`XAML`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="TreeView1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TreeViewItem.Selected="TreeViewItem_OnItemSelected">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= iName}" Margin="5,0" />    
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Instead of adding tvi like earlier,i do this:

```
//  node.Items.Add(tvi); //for non-xaml approach
var ti = new TreeItem { iName = ni.name};
node.Items.Add(ti);
```

My `TreeItem` class looks like this:

```
namespace DeveloperTool
{
    public class TreeItem
    {
        public string iName
        {
            get; set;
        }     
    }
}
```

Even for this approach I use, I see `TreeViewItems` with names `DeveloperTool`. `TreeItem` instead of the actual name I am binding to. For simplicity i just tried with the `TextBlock` first (excluding the image). Can someone please review what i am doing wrong here. Both approaches result in the same kind of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue based upon your samples is the need for a header template.  Add this snippet to your TreeView declaration...

```
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image  Margin="2"  Source="{Binding ...}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
```

This gives you a HeaderTemplate that you can bind to.  Of course you have to add the right binding features to get this snippet to compile and work, but otherwise most of your existing code can be salvaged.

Comment: so i should get rid of the itemtemplate and use it in Resources instead?

Comment: Yes, the Xaml I posted sets the HeaderTemplate property and that's what you're after based upon the code and Xaml you posted.

Comment: Thank you.that did it.i have more questions to make my thing working, but it is probably good idea to post another question regarding it.

Comment: You're fine, the only REAL hangup was the headertemplate part :)

Comment: Sure :)
But i couldnt really succeed.Posted it here.

Comment: Sure :). but couldnt really succeed .posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879631/dynamically-changing-imges-for-treeviewitems